# Changing display name takes too long. Flutter and FIrebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make a list of my users and the display name takes a bit to change after update profile but by that time the list already has a null in the name section.

```
final User user = (await
    _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailR,
      password: passwordR,
    )
    ).user;
    user.updateProfile(displayName: usernameR);

    emailc.clear();
    passwordc.clear();
    usernamec.clear();

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String dt = "${now.day.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}/${now.month.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}/${now.year.toString()} ${now.hour.toString()}:${now.minute.toString()}";

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
      "id": user.uid,
      "name": user.displayName,
      "email": user.email,
      "created_at": dt,
    });
```

The reason why I think its a timing problem is because on my main page where it says the username the first time when I register, it'll show "hey, null" and every time after that it'll show the correct username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`updateProfile` call](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateProfile.html) is an asynchronous operation, and `user.displayName` won't be updated until that operation has completed. Luckily it returns a `Future`, so you can just use `await` on the call to wait for it to complete, in the same way you already do for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

So:

```
await user.updateProfile(displayName: usernameR);
```

Answer (score 0):

bro its problem you fetching and send data every things takes time so for this purpose you need to use circularprogress indicator its take 1 or 2 second bro first its change your name in firstore and then its fetch from firestore so avoid from this use Circularprogress indictor when your name is null.hope you will like my sugestion